# can my sysadmin at work see my network activity when i use work computer in my home and connected to my private router?

Tags: networking

Can Sysadmin can monitor my browsing at my home router

I have a computer at my work.
When I take the computer home and browse from my home wifi
can my sysadmin at work know my activity?

Comment: do you use a VPN when connected from home? can you view the installed software? are any proxy server settings enabled? absent a VPN or proxy, the only option the admins would have would be software installed to log the activity or transmit it via an agent of some kind.

Comment: Some answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/184346/748131) might be helpful. It is safest to assume your work can see everything you do on a work computer.